# Printing from a Pixma ip1900 printer says "printer stopped"

Tags: 10.10, drivers, printing, canon

I have installed the drivers for pixma ip1900 printer, printed a test page, but when I try to print a document fromm open office I get a message saying 'printer stopped'.

I am running 10.10 Maverick Meerkat. Can you help please? The drivers I am using are for Karmic Koala, does this make a difference?

I have installed cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb and cnijfilter-ip1900series_3.00-1_i386.deb. I installed them with a deb installer in synaptic package manager.

Comment: Further specify the drivers you installed (and how), please.

Comment: cnijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb  cnijfilter-common-3.00-1.tar.gz  cnijfilter-ip1900series_3.00-1_i386.deb  I installed them with a deb installer in synaptic package manager   thanks takkat

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards